# Storing the last input text whilst using the POST method with PHP

Tags: php, post, input, local-storage, store

**The idea:**

I have been trying to create a one-way chat system based on predictions from the user, using pre-set automatic responses through the server side.

**The problem:**

What I have so far works great, although the problem I have now is that I can't store the last user inputted message locally for the chat to flow in messages without using lots of `_GET`'s.

**With my current code:**

```
if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
    $test = htmlentities($_POST['test']);
    echo "<span class='you'>".$name."</span>: ".$test;
    if (preg_match('~\b(?:about)\b~', $test)) {
        echo '<br />'.$about;
    } else if (preg_match('~\b(?:projects?|works?)\b~i', $test)) {
        echo '<br />'.$projects;
    } else if (preg_match('~\b(?:contact|email|inquiry)\b~', $test)) {
        echo '<br />'.$contact;
    } else {
        echo "<br />Error!";
    }
}
```

For example, if the user types `projects` into the input, `$projects` echo's correctly, but after if the user types `about`, `$about` does show, but the previous `projects` message disappears.

**What I have tried:**

- I've tried to put each `if` in its own `isset`.
- Thought about a loop that makes a new input after every message, although I believe this is probably not efficient use of PHP, I need to find a more minimal way.

Answer (score 2):

You could use so `AJAX` that old messages won't disappear on submit.

Have an `<ul>` for the chat messages.
When user posts, create a `<li>` with his message and another one for the answer, and keep adding them...

Comment: Thanks! Although I'm trying to find a pure PHP solution to this. :)

Comment: @Rahul you would have to store the previous messages in (for example)session and then loop through them and echo the associated message for each of them. That's not really cool method. You should just use AJAX